# The "exception was caught" breakpoint dialog window has an extra '>' char when you catch a generic exception?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I noticed something odd with a fault exception from a WCF service and was able to recreate it:

Create a new console app and add these types:

```
class TestException<T> : Exception where T : IError, new() { }
interface IError { }
class NewError : IError { }
class NormalException : Exception { }
```

In the `Main` function, add this code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        throw new NormalException();
    }
    catch (NormalException ne)
    { //break point here 
    }
    try
    {
        throw new TestException<NewError>();
    }
    catch (TestException<NewError> ge)
    {//break point here
    }
}
```

When the break hits on the first catch the window will show like this:

[image: Normal exception break point]

When the generic exception is hit, you'll get this window:

[image: generic exception break point]

Notice the extra > char in the message.

Is this normal and expected, or something I report?

Can anyone try to duplicate this on VS 2012 ?

Comment: This is a bug and I've confirmed that it still exists on Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: This looks like a bug in VS. I strongly recommend you file this on MSConnect: http://connect.microsoft.com/

Comment: Ok thanks for confirming that. I've filed a report here. https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/782789/extra-character-in-exception-break-point-dialog-window

Comment: @asawyer - I can close if you want, but you could also add your own answer once you've properly confirmed this as a bug.

Comment: If the type parameter can be written without a period (from namespace access), the problem seems to go away. For example if you move your `NewError` class declaration to outside the `namespace scratcpad { ... }` block so that the class resides in the global namespace, the error goes away. The interface and the generic constraint on `TestException<>` are not necessary to reproduce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this may or may not get fixed in an upcoming release then:

> Posted by Microsoft on 4/3/2013 at 11:29 AM Thanks for reporting this
>   issue. We will consider fixing this in a future release.    Thanks, 
>   Visual Studio Debugger Team